Why are the same flat surfaces showing two different shades?
Creating a paperback book. I add a fold to the front cover by creating a narrow channel cut into the surface.

However, when I add a bevel modifier and shade smooth, the flat surfaces to the left of that fold are clearly a different shade to the right.

I select harden normals in the shader of the bevel modifier and it makes it even worse. Adjusting the smooth by angle doesn't help. If I try to shade flat the two sides, it stops the bevel from being smooth.
Why is this happening when the normals on these two flat surfaces are in the same direction?


Do a face orientation check:

Everything should be blue. If you see reds, you go to edit mode, select all a and recalculate normal shif+n.
